How click on an external url and open in default browser (Chrome) in the same tab that already has the same website open instead of opening a new tab?
Practical example:
I have the website www.globo.com/vasco-vs-flamengo/ open in my default browser (Google Chrome)
They sent me the URL www.globo.com/palmeiras-vs-cruzeiro/ on Telegram.
If I click to open in the default browser (Google Chrome) a new tab will open.
But... instead, specifically for this website I would like that if there is any page linked to this website already open, then it would load this URL in the same tab instead of opening a new one, because the site does not accept multiple tabs open on its site and may generate access blocks because it thinks I am scraping data.
Is there a way to do this?

Possible with extensions. Quick look and none like this exists, this is the closest: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf with the URL highlight functionality
